# Evernote API - Getting contents of shared notebooks

Tags: api, evernote

I'm looking for a way to retrieve contents of shared notebooks without authentication. I've looked through the official api documentation, but couldn't find one.

example feed : https://www.evernote.com/pub/karis612/foods/feed

visit the link above. it's an rss feed from my own notebook shared publicly. in the rss content, we can find two links for articles. is there any way to get article contents from those urls?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the content of shared notebooks through looking at the source of the shared notebook page. It can be found in the chunk similar to the one below:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"
  title="[Name of Notebook]"
  href="http://www.evernote.com/shard/s31/pub/5145629/[Evernote Username]/[Name of Notebook]/rss.jsp?max=25&sort=2&search=" />
```

Then, you can create a feed from feedburner (or any other service you want, but I have only tried feedburner) with this link if you discard the `?max=25&sort=2&search=` at the end of the link.

Not sure if this is any help to you, but best of luck!